# Building a half-bridge zero-voltage switching inverter for induction heating

Tags: inverter, mosfet-driver, zvs, half-bridge, induction-heater

I am not an electrical professional so please me patient with me.

I'm trying to build a half-bridge ZVS inverter for a small induction heater (I want to try to do some small scale welding). I tried my best to make a realistic simulation using an AC supply, rectifier, and a dual gate driver (boost).

In the below diagrams, L1 would be my heater inductor and R1 represents the metal I will be heating up. I am unsure why this design is unable to zero voltage switching, or even oscillate. I tried changing whether my (snubber?) capacitor C4 is in parallel or in series with my load, but I think I made it worse.

Is there something fundamentally incorrect about my circuit or math that I am not understanding?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there something fundamentally incorrect about my circuit*

You need to use a correctly designed bootstrapped driver circuit because: -

[image]

It's wrong because it connects to -5 volts and that means the gate-source voltage on the upper MOSFET will be taken to a negative voltage that far exceeds the device specifications.

I cannot be 100% sure (because you haven't provided details of the driver) but, the connection covered by the red circle should be broken and, the driver pin connected to N04 (the main output).

C4 also looks problematic also. I would be considering series resonant tuning and not parallel tuning. However, you should operate at a frequency slightly above resonance so that the half-bridge is driving a net inductive circuit.

Comment: Thank you sir for your detailed answer! Vn04 Vn03 and IL1 oscillate much better now (image in link below). The gate driver is a default boost dual gate driver (also included in link) within QSPICE. However, the magnitude of current and voltage now decreases consistently; is it right to assume that it is due to incorrect capacitance values?

I found f = 3804 = 1 / 2*pi*sqrt(L1*C4). I increased it to 4000Hz on Vsin to make it net inductive like you said, but the graphs output similar decreasing current and voltage amplitudes:

https://imgur.com/a/iwLk8vr

Comment: @Brick that's good. For your other questions raise a new post and add details like what you did in this question above. Link back to this question too and also add on a comment below my answer here linking me to your new post. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.